# Oath2 Redirect URL Issues : Invalid redirect URL

Tags: php

I am using Oauth2 client of Preview Technologies but it says Invalid redirect URL. I was using their official library from https://github.com/previewtechnologies/oauth2-client. Anybody faced that problem before?

Answer (score 0):

@imran, I am from Preview Technologies. you can follow our github readme file and see

```
$provider = new \Previewtechs\Oauth2\Client\Provider([
    'clientId' => '{previewtechs_client_id}',    // The client ID assigned to you by Preview Technologies
    'clientSecret' => '{previewtechs_client_secret}',   // The client secret assigned to you by Preview Technologies
    'redirectUri' => '{your_redirect_url}'
]);
```

But still if doesn't work, then you need to tell us to make your redirect url whitelisted.